# Save Revisions for Template Manager

Tags: revisions

I can't remember how to enable revisions for templates in Expression Engine 2.11.3.   Does anyone have any idea? Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's in the template general preferences admin.php?cp/design/global_template_preferences